# Why does using an input group break the baseline alignment in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I have a form with a label next to an input, in plain HTML, and both are inline (or inline block), then they are aligned by their baseline. But when using bootstrap and putting the input in an input group, it seems they get aligned by their bottom.

I tried to replicate this without bootstrap, but I couldn't, it just works. I created fiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/pupeno/9aJCF/3/

The HTML is:

```
<p>A case working, with just an input:</p>
<div class="form-group without-input-group">
    <label>label</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value" />
</div>
<hr/>
<p>A case broken with the same HTML structure, but not using bootstrap:</p>
<div class="without-bootstrap">
    <label>label</label>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value" />
        <span>addon</span>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<p>The broken situation, with the input group:</p>
<div class="form-group with-input-group">
    <label>label</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">addon</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.without-input-group input {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.without-bootstrap .group {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-table;
}
.without-bootstrap .group input {
    display: table-cell;
}
.without-bootstrap .group span {
    display: table-cell;
}


.with-input-group .input-group {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the input group is `display: inline-table;` and the label is outside the input-group.
If you inspect the input-group-addon element, you see that it is set to `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`.
If you move the label inside the input-group and style it same as the input-group-addon it lines up correctly.

```
<div class="form-group with-input-group">    
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">addon</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.input-group label {
    padding: 4px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/N62he/

Comment: Labels shouldn't be inside input groups in Bootstrap.

Comment: Also, I updated the fiddle to show the case of the label being properly aligned next to the inline-table.

Comment: When you apply the properties from the input-group to the label and the form-group it works. http://jsfiddle.net/9aJCF/5/